# insert data and time in a database column

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

How to insert data and time in database column.

```
    create table test(sno integer,name varchar,createdtime timestamp);
    insert into test values(1,'ASD',to_date('22/08/2015 8:30:00 AM','DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS AM);
```

But when i run the same above query in sqlfiddle its showing to_date is not recognized function. Please suggest how can I insert date and time in database table.

Comment: Since your table has a `TIMESTAMP` column instead of a date column, you should use `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TO_DATE`

Answer (score 1):

you should use like this with Postgre/Oracle:

```
create table test(sno integer,name varchar,createdtime timestamp);
insert into test values(1,'ASD',to_date('22/08/2015 8:30:00 AM','DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS AM'));
```

'MM' is the month with number 1-12, Mon is the abbr of month like Jan. `DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS AM` is ok.

[sqlfiddle sample link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/31473/3/0)

Comment: sorry to mention late, i'm using oracle and in the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/31473/3/0 when i modified the database to oracle11g from postgress it keep on saying please build schema..somehow sqlfiddle is not a handy for me anytime, am i doing anything wrong in sqlfiddle as it always hangs in building the schema or loading the schema. Thanks.

Comment: @user3684675 - Your `create table` syntax is invalid in Oracle.  a `varchar` needs a length (i.e. `name varchar2(20)`).  That's the error you're getting in SQLFiddle.

Comment: Please find the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46b0d/1/0 . It is throwing exception No signature of method: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP.format() is applicable for argument types ..... when databse is selected as oracle11g.thanks.

Comment: Right, if you change to Oracle, you need to set varchar with a length like varchar(20). see this link [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e825d/1/0)

Comment: @user3684675, see this one [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68266/9/0), because the runtime can't display a timestamp directly, so you can do a change to transform the date to a string like `select to_char(createdtime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from test;`